# Sql server: How many request can be executed at the same time with the same connection?

Tags: sql

As i said in the title, i'm researching How many request can be executed at the same time with the same connection on sql server, and what can make this number change.
Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: If you refer to a .NET `SqlConnection`(for example) clarify your question, because then it depends on [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i am using microsoft sql server.

Comment: And yes i was refering to a .net sql connection, like for example if i have 500 user that want to login throught my API at the exacr same time, will the 500 one will have a delay or ?

Comment: Like @TimSchmelter suggested, look at .net SqlConnection pooling. It's the way you do this kind of thing. Individual connections in a pool can handle one active query / SQL statement each at a time. Each connection is a serially reusable resource, not a concurrent-access resource. The pool handles the serially-reusable part of that for you very nicely.

Answer (score -1):

> How many requests can be executed at the same time with the same connection?

One.

If you want concurrent requests use multiple connections.

Comment: But i have only one account configure on my Web API, but many clients can connect throught this , and send many many request , will there be any delay request issue ?